# MySQL corrupted date insert NOW()

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I have a column in database whose type is `datetime`. Each time user changes something this gets updated to note that user changed something on website at this date/time.

The query that im using is:

```
INSERT INTO Test(bunch columns, ChangedAt)  VALUES (bunch values, NOW())
```

Now after couple of days i checked the table and there was one row having this value for the `ChangedAt` column:

```
2020-11-14 00:00:00
```

any ides how the hell it got `2020`? and why there is `time` **00:00:00**

thanks

Comment: Out of curiousity, can you run `date` on the machine that the database is on and see what that says?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only 2 possible reasons.
computer date was wrong...  wich would be a coincidence to get 00:00:00

or the row was updated/inserted like that.

> MySQL recognizes DATETIME and TIMESTAMP values in these formats:
>
> As a string in either 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' or 'YY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'
>   format. A “relaxed” syntax is permitted here, too: Any punctuation
>   character may be used as the delimiter between date parts or time
>   parts. For example, '2012-12-31 11:30:45', '2012^12^31 11+30+45',
>   '2012/12/31 11*30*45', and '2012@12@31 11^30^45' are equivalent.
>
> As a string with no delimiters in either 'YYYYMMDDHHMMSS' or
>   'YYMMDDHHMMSS' format, provided that the string makes sense as a date.
>   For example, '20070523091528' and '070523091528' are interpreted as
>   '2007-05-23 09:15:28', but '071122129015' is illegal (it has a
>   nonsensical minute part) and becomes '0000-00-00 00:00:00'.
>
> As a number in either YYYYMMDDHHMMSS or YYMMDDHHMMSS format, provided
>   that the number makes sense as a date. For example, 19830905132800 and
>   830905132800 are interpreted as '1983-09-05 13:28:00'

as you can see..  it would be hard to insert a different value by mistake and get it inserted... 20201114000000 in your case...

Comment: so i will assume that some kind of magic happened and screwed up that one record. :) thanks